# Another way to write this method without using an Array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Is there another way to write this method without using an Array, like with a `for each` and `if` statements? I just want to see if there is a more simple way to write it.

```
/**
 * Write a method that prints the number of movies of each star rating
 */
public void printRatingReport()
{
    int[] numMovies = new int[5];
    for (Movie m : movies){
        numMovies[m.getStarRating()]++;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<=4; i++){
        System.out.println(i+ " star movies " + numMovies[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: A "more simple" way to write it?  I wouldn't expect so.  That's about as simple an implementation as I could imagine.

Comment: @LouisWasserman some people will even use Streams rather than use a loop. ;) see my answer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey he is not even using arr length to get array's length  and you are suggesting him to lambda expressions ? Are you sure you are making it simple ?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I did see your answer, and considered it more complex than the original code.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < numMovies.length; ++i) { System.out.printf("%d stars movies %d%n", i, numMovies[i]); }` is a bit nicer style but apart from the java 8 streams the solution is fine enough - given a rating between 0 and 4.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I am not going to argue with you on that one ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Java 8 you can do

```
SortedMap<StarRating, Long> starCount = movies.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.getStarRating(), 
                                            TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting());

starCount.forEach((rating, count) -> System.out.println(rating + " star movies " + count));
```

Comment: Ideally, the star rating would be replaced with an enum instead of an int, which this code will handle nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Use enum. That way you could use foreach and possibly change the rating system from 5 stars to 2, 6 or more as code would be more cohesive.

```
enum Stars {
    One, Two, Three, Four, Five
}

public void starRatingReport() {
    for (Stars starRating : Stars.values()) {
        int number = 0;
        for (Movie movie : movies) {
            if (movie.getRating() == starRating) {
                number++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(number + " Movies with rating " + starRating);
    }
}
```

You could also use Properties but in my opinion they are bit more complicated.